# Salesforce Workflows order issue

Tags: workflow

We have multiple Workflows that that each update the same field depending on what values are set.  The field being updated is a Status field that will only increase as more checkboxes are checked.

Our Workflows will only update the Status field if the applicable checkbox is selected and the current status is not higher than the status the Workflow will set.  (i.e. Worflow_status_2 checks for checbox_2 and makes sure that the Status field is not already Statuts_3, Status_4, etc.)

In all environments except for one, the checkboxes can be checked in any order and the Status value will be updated to the greatest possible status based on the selected checkboxes.  In the problem environemnt, the Status field is not always updated and when it is, it does not go to the highest possible Status based on the selected checkboxes.

To try to fix this problem environment, I turned on `Re-evaluate Workflow Rules after Field Change` on each of the Field Updates.  This did not help.

There is no evidence of the Status value dropping (as it should be impossible based on each of the Workflow conditions).  It just appears that the lower-level status Workflows are firing and their update is taking precedence over the higher-level Workflows.

Although I know there is no way to control the order of operations for Workflows, is there a concept that I am missing that would cause this one environment to not perform as expected?  Is there another way to ensure the that the higher-level Workflows fire as expected?

Comment: Why are multiple workflow rules needed here and not one workflow rule with a formula for the criteria?

Comment: I might have seen an oddity where the order of execution of workflow actions correlate to the chronological (time) order that they were created, if memory serves me right. As an aside, a simple trigger can sometimes be a lot more convenient than a complex web of workflows.

Comment: I would prefer to use a Trigger to fix this issue but we required to keep custom dev down to an absolute minimum on this engagement.